# Python Printing to Console Problematic 1 in Every 1000 Tries

Tags: python, console, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

Out of 30,000 lines printed to console, approximately 30 lines are problematic.

Expected:

```
[OK] http://example.com/details.asp?id=27692 200 32
[OK] http://example.com/details.asp?id=27065 200 32
[OK] http://example.com/details.asp?id=27391 200 32
[OK] http://example.com/details.asp?id=27200 200 32
[OK] http://example.com/details.asp?id=27205 200 32
[OK] http://example.com/details.asp?id=27397 200 32
[OK] http://example.com/details.asp?id=27057 200 32
```

But, sometimes we get:

```
[NotFound] http://example.com/details.asp?id=621 200 32
[NotFound] http://example.com/details.asp?id=693 200 32
[NotFound] http://example.com/details.asp?id=720 200 32
[NotFound] http://example.com/details.asp?id=685 200 32
[NotFound] http://example.com/details.asp?id=741 200 32
[NotFound] http://example.com/details.asp?id=742 200 32[NotFound] http://example.com/details.asp?id=733 200 32

[NotFound] http://example.com/details.asp?id=689 200 32
[NotFound] http://example.com/details.asp?id=695 200 32
```

My code is no different than the sample code in the [aiomultiprocessing library](https://github.com/omnilib/aiomultiprocess), with the exception of parsing the response of the web request in the get function, and conditionally printing with:

```
if '<font size=2><STRONG></STRONG></font><br>' not in data:
    print(f'[OK] {url} {status} {size}')
else:
    print(f'[NotFound] {url} {status} {size}')
```

aiomultiprocessing example code I modified:

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import request
from aiomultiprocess import Pool

async def get(url):
    async with request("GET", url) as response:
        return await response.text("utf-8")

async def main():
    urls = ["https://jreese.sh", ...]
    async with Pool() as pool:
        async for result in pool.map(get, urls):
            ...  # process result
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Python 3.7
    asyncio.run(main())
    
    # Python 3.6
    # loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: This smells like two `print()` statements are happening concurrently, and the output is mingled together.

Comment: Simply use locks when printing, I think that should work